# SpriteKit + Swift - How do I move a node with easing?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, easing

I'm creating a game in SpriteKit using Swift.
I have a node on the scene and when the user touches the screen, I want the node to move up with easeOut. When the user releases the screen the node should fall to the ground.
I'm looking for a SKAction which can move a node with easeOut.
Can anyone help me making that action?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just set Gesture events and change the gravity of a node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to achieve this through SKActions triggering movement you are after the `timingMode` property of SKAction.

`someAction.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut`

As Özgür is writing in the comment though this can also be achieved with physics, which might be better, depending on your requirement.